# Homology of Alexander Horned Sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups, low-dimensional-topology

I am taking a course in homology this semester, and so far we have only examined spaces/surfaces that the simplicial structures are rather easy to find. I was curious about the Alexander Horned Sphere, and how one would approach finding its homology groups.

I figure $H_{0}(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, as the horned sphere is path connected (I think), and I know the fundamental group is infinitely generated, but what explicitly would be $H_{1}(X)$?

And then that begs the question of how to find $H_{2} (X)$.

Looking more for a conversation than a proof, just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Not an expert, but I thought the horned sphere was an embedding of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in which case its homology groups are just those of $S^2$. (The homology of the complement would be an interesting question though.)

Comment: @hunter Surprisingly, the homology of the complement is the same as the homology of the complement of the standard embedding. This follows from Alexander duality.

Comment: @ConnorMalin neat! Can't be a coincidence that these are both named after Alexander.

Comment: @hunter I am sorry, I do not see how the homology groups could be the same if the horned sphere has a different fundamental group. I agree, the homology of the complement is also an interesting question

Comment: @mathishard By the "simple" Hurewicz theorem, the first homology group of a space is the abelianisation of its fundamental group. Here, Alexander's duality tells you that the first homology group of the complement is $0$, so the fundamental group has a trivial abelianisation. I don't know what this group is exactly though.
edit : a discussion about this group is in Hatcher, p. 171/172

Comment: @mathishard they have the same fundamental group as well. (but the complement has a different fundamental group from the complement of the standard embedding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Alexander horned sphere $A$ is the image of an "exotic" embedding $\phi : S^2 \to \mathbb R^3$. Hence $A \approx S^2$ and $H_n(A) = \mathbb Z$ for $n = 0,2$ and $H_n(A) = 0$ else.